# In Emacs how do I mark a string when inside the same string?

Tags: emacs

Let's say I have an output which contains:

> {"I know not with what weapons World War III will be fought, but World
>   War IV will be fought with sticks and stones.", "A happy family is but
>   an earlier heaven.", "Heaven has no rage like love to hatred turned,
>   Nor hell a fury like a woman scorned."}

And my cursor is inside one of the string (after the word 'fought'):

> "I know not with what weapons World War III will be fought|, but World
>    War IV will be fought with sticks and stones."

And I would like to copy that whole string.
Generally what I do is, I go to the start of the of the string, move one character back to the " and press "C-M-SPC" and select the string.

But I find that cumbersome.
Is there a way to select the string within the string directly?

Also is it possible to select a string if it has escaped double quotes like:

> "And she said \"Learning is what most adults| will do for a living in
>   the 21st century.\" that yesterday"

In above if my cursor is after 'adults' it should be able to select the outer string properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

expand-region is what you're after.  [Screencast](http://emacsrocks.com/e09.html) and [project](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function:

```
(defun copy-quoted-string ()
  (interactive)
  "Copies the quoted text, ignoring the escaped quotes"
  (save-excursion
     (search-backward-regexp "[^\\]\"")
     (forward-char)
     (mark-sexp)
     (kill-ring-save (point) (mark))))

;this is for testing
(global-set-key [f2] 'copy-quoted-string)
```

For testing I used the following string:

```
"text text", "text \"quoted text\" text"
```

When I press F2, when the cursor is located inside "text text", this string is copied into clipboard. When I am in "text \"quoted text\" text" - this string is copied.

Answer (score 1):

I found this another alternative:
Thanks to Vedang.

[Reference](https://github.com/vedang/emacs-config/blob/master/configuration/utility-functions.el#L72):

```
;;; Function to mark complete word, and expand to sentence etc.
;;; by Nikolaj Schumacher, 2008-10-20. Released under GPL.
(defun semnav-up (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (when (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
    (if (> arg 0)
        (progn
          (skip-syntax-forward "^\"")
          (goto-char (1+ (point)))
          (decf arg))
      (skip-syntax-backward "^\"")
      (goto-char (1- (point)))
      (incf arg)))
  (up-list arg))


;;; by Nikolaj Schumacher, 2008-10-20. Released under GPL.
(defun extend-selection (arg &optional incremental)
  "Select the current word.
Subsequent calls expands the selection to larger semantic unit."
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                     (or (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
                         (eq last-command this-command))))
  (if incremental
      (progn
        (semnav-up (- arg))
        (forward-sexp)
        (mark-sexp -1))
    (if (> arg 1)
        (extend-selection (1- arg) t)
      (if (looking-at "\\=\\(\\s_\\|\\sw\\)*\\_>")
          (goto-char (match-end 0))
        (unless (memq (char-before) '(?\) ?\"))
          (forward-sexp)))
      (mark-sexp -1))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'extend-selection)
```